# editing messages with discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to edit my bots sent messages, but I'm getting an error

```py
@client.command()
async def edit(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send('testing')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    message.edit(content='v2')
```

Error:

```
 RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Message.edit' was never awaited
  message.edit(content='v2')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

And by the way, is there any way of editing a message by simply having the message ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time.sleep()` is a blocking call, meaning that it pretty much screws up your script. What you'll instead want to use is `await asyncio.sleep()`.

Also, `edit()` is a coroutine, so it needs to be awaited. Here is what your command should look like:

```py
import asyncio # if you haven't already

@client.command()
async def edit(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send('testing')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
    await message.edit(content='v2')
```

To edit a message via ID, you'll need the channel that it came from:

```py
@client.command()
async def edit(ctx, msg_id: int = None, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
    if not msg_id:
        channel = client.get_channel(112233445566778899) # the message's channel
        msg_id = 998877665544332211 # the message's id
    elif not channel:
        channel = ctx.channel
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
    await msg.edit(content="Some content!")
```

The usage for this command would be `!edit 112233445566778899 #message-channel-origin` assuming that the prefix is `!`, and don't bother using the channel argument if the message is in the channel you're executing the command in.

---

**References:**

- [`Message.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.edit)
- [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep)
- [`Messageable.fetch_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)

Comment: thanks! Is there any way of editing a message by the ID?

Comment: Just edited my answer for that :^) Hope it works for you

Comment: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Channel'

Comment: Re-edited, sorry haha - I forget about using `TextChannel` sometimes

Comment: is there any way of editing the without putting the ID and channel all the time?

Comment: If you run the edit command in the channel where the message is, you won't need to use the channel argument, and you can just use the ID

Comment: Is there any way to verify that message is changed? If I delete the message, edit process still pass without any exception

Comment: @alper To verify the message is changed, I would recommend looking at the actual [`.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.content) or [`.clean_content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.clean_content) of the message, and compare it to whatever new string you want to replace the content with.  As for the second part of your comment, I don't fully understand what you mean, could you clarify please?

Comment: @Diggy LIke manually when I delete the edited message on the discord , and still edit() message applied to the previously deleted message, I believe an exception is created